# Tox InterpreterNotFound Gitlab-CI Pipeline

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, tox

I need some help with testing my python package using `tox` in a gitlab-ci pipeline:

I want to test my package on multiple versions. For this, I can write the following in my `tox.ini`:

```ini
[tox]
envlist = py{310, 311}

[testenv]
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    python -m pytest tests -s
```

Running the command `tox` works locally, as I have multiple python versions installed via conda (I believe this is the reason).

Until now, I have always also tested my package in my gitlab pipeline: (`.gitlab-ci.yml`)

```yaml
image: python:3.11

unit-test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - pip install tox
        - tox -r
```

This causes the pipeline to fail with the following message:

```
ERROR:  py310: InterpreterNotFound: python3.10
  py311: commands succeeded
```

Is there a gitlab ci container image already out there, that includes multiple python versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with for some of my projects:

```yaml
'.review':
  before_script:
    - 'python -m pip install tox'
  script:
    - 'export TOX_ENV="${CI_JOB_NAME##review}"'
    - 'tox'

'review py3.9':
  extends: '.review'
  image: 'python:3.9'

'review py3.12':
  extends: '.review'
  image: 'python:3.12'
```

I have not really looked into this in a while, so there might be better solutions nowadays. Anyway, the advantage of this solution is that it avoids repeating the `script` part for each Python version. The "trick" is to set the `TOX_ENV` environment variable to something like `py3.9` or `py3.11`, which is done be extracting this value from the name of the job which is contained in the `CI_JOB_NAME` environment variable set by the GitLab CI pipeline runner.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary, simple, and easily maintainable solution is using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```yaml
image: python:latest

unit-test-3.11:
    image: python:3.11
    stage: test
    script:
        - pip install tox
        - tox -r -e py311

unit-test-3.10:
    image: python:3.10
    stage: test
    script:
        - pip install tox
        - tox -r -e py310
```

---

Note:

I believe an even better solution exists, that doesn't require multiple images/jobs (as https://github.com/AntoineD/docstring-inheritance/blob/main/.github/workflows/tests.yml doesn't for example).

However, until someone posts a better solution here, I will mark this one as correct.